# How can I update an iOS Widget daily at 12:00 AM automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

Xcode provides this code to update 5 times an hour:

```
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

I tried this but it doesn't update right.:

```
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        let currentDate = Date()
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(..)
        entries.append(entry)

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
```

When I run on my device it updates, but it doesn't feel like it is updated consistently. It is definitely not updating once a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve got two problems:

1. Your only timeline entry is in the future. You need to add one at the current time (or earlier) for the widget to use now.
2. You're adding a day to `currentDate`, which is the current date *and time*, so if this runs at 2:30pm today it would refresh at 2:30pm tomorrow.

Give this a try:

```swift
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {

    // Generate a timeline with one entry that refreshes at midnight.
    let currentDate = Date()
    let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
    let endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startOfDay)!
    
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: startOfDay)
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(endOfDay))
    completion(timeline)
}
```

Here I’ve used the `Calendar.current.startOfDay()` method to get a Date to use for my entry. Then I add a day to it to get midnight tonight, which I use in the Timeline’s refresh policy.

Comment: It is still updating at a time not 12:00AM